# How configure windows to execute .bat file automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

All my .bat files are opening automatically in notepad. Anyone know what kind of file I need to associate it? I tried to associate to "Windows command processor", but it only opened the "command-prompt", and didn't execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the .bat file association in the registry. See [this link](https://superuser.com/a/53950) for more details.

You should just be able to remove the "UserChoice" sub-folder.

Comment: And of course, be very careful when you're messing with the registry.

Comment: @CodyPiersall - Very true, as suggested in the link I posted you should backup the registry if you aren't sure!